# How do you link to a website with a button that has a function providing the link?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, hyperlink

Im using a function to return a string to a button onclick. That string contains a link to google. When I press the button, it does not redirect to google. Im very new to using html and java.

```html
<button id="linkBtn" type="button" onclick="window.location.href = getGoogleLink();">Google</button>

<script>

 function getGoogleLink(){
        string google = "'https://www.google.com/'"
        return google;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im very new to using html and java.

You mean JavaScript.

Please take a look at the following post. It handles redirection via JavaScript. [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

And please don't use the HTML event handler registration attribute `onclick`. It's bad practice. Add an ID to the DOM element and do everything inside your JavaScript.

```js
(() => {
  
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // get the button element from your HTML
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    
    // register click listener
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
    });
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Redirect to Google</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `location.replace('address')`.

for e.g.

```
<button id="linkBtn" onclick="redirect('https://www.google.com/')" type="button">Google</button>

<script>

    function redirect(url) {
        location.replace(url)
    }

</script>
```

At the top, I wrote a function to get URL and change windows location, URL came from:

```
onclick="redirect('https://www.google.com/')"
```